# Has anyone asked for a "suggest edit" button, or is the rollback feature enough?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I would like to edit e.g. [this](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/31208/can-philosophy-justify-itself), but it seems a bit impertinent when the asker is active, as well as general users with more reputation than me.

Would it be OK to request a "suggest edit" button for the site?

Answer (score 1):

I rolled back the edit because it changed too much. Typically, big changes are discussed in the comments first and then made by the OP if he agrees. I therefore do not see the need for such a feature (though don't have any kind of authority on this).

Once you have earned 1000 reputation and the "suggest edit" feature turns into an instantaneous edit feature, you're expected to know what to edit or not to edit. There are always borderline cases of course and that's fine, that's what comments are for.

Comment: it was a verbose edit, but it didn't change what was said IMHO. ofc if the 1st version really *was* not clear, then it's gonna be impossible to clarify it with any reliability.

Comment: @MATHEMETICIAN your edit changed "philosophy justifying itself" into "justifying knowledge", which is not really the same.

Comment: yes, because i thought that one of the assumptions in the post might itself be questioned. sometimes questions do get poor answers along the lines of "your assumption is wrong"

Comment: i mean i can roll back to the same edit but change the title to "can philosophy and science justify themselves" if the title is the issue. but yeah

Comment: Your edit shouldn't change the meaning of the post. If you want to question one of the assumptions in the post, you should use comments for that. If a question receives poor answers, flag them and vote them down, although "your assumption is wrong" can be a valid answer in some cases (e.g. some answers [here](http://philosophy.stackexchange.com/q/31195/2953) have that form).

Comment: ok i'll remember it. it can generate poor answers tho, IME

Comment: btw i don't think my title was "justifying knowledge", but i don't seem able to see old edits? either way, if it's a mistake to question an assumption, in an edit, then i won't do so again. i felt it added clarity btw